# What tools are people using to create test scripts for Laravel PHPunit/Selenium?

Tags: laravel, selenium, phpunit, integration-testing

I want to run `PHPUnit` tests in `Laravel` that make use of `Selenium`. I've been watching a few videos and it all seems fairly simple.

I'd like to know whats the easiest way to write these test scripts? For example selenium IDE allows you to generate large tests in seconds by recording your actions in the web app but I can't see an option to export this into a format that `Laravel` can use? What are my options here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read about [Codeception](http://codeception.com/)?

It's enviroment for testing app (not only unit test but also functionals and acceptence test) where you can assign **Selenium** or **PhantomJS**.